# Write in terminal with applescript app in xcode

Tags: xcode, terminal, applescript

I would like to write in the terminal with an applescript app in Xcode but it does not work.

Applescript code:

```
on ButtonTermialClicked_(sender)
    tell application "Terminal" to activate

    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Terminal"
            set frontmost to true
            do shell script keystroke "example text"
        end tell
    end tell
end ButtonTermianlClicked_
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**

I would like to insert is `"chflags hidden"` and then hide a folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why GUI scripting and `System Events`? Terminal.app is scriptable.

```
on ButtonTermialClicked_(sender)
     tell application "Terminal"
        activate
        do script "chflags hidden /Users/myself/Desktop/Test" in window 1
     end tell
end ButtonTermianlClicked_
```

or even without Terminal.app

```
on ButtonTermialClicked_(sender)
    do shell script "chflags hidden /Users/myself/Desktop/Test"
end ButtonTermianlClicked_
```

`/Users/myself/Desktop/Test` represents the full path to the folder. If the path contains space characters you have to wrap the path in single quotes.